# How to detach a tmux session that itself already in a tmux?

Tags: tmux

I've opened a tmux session on my local machine, and ssh'd into the remote machine. After this, I typed `tmux attach` on the remote machine, then I got a remote tmux session on my local tmux session.

Now I want to detach from the remote tmux session, I've tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> but it detached my local tmux session rather than the remote one.

How can I detach the remote tmux sesstion?

Comment: I prefer `tmux detach`, it doesn't require a keyboard since it's a command.

Comment: `C-b d` is good to detach in the normal fashion, only 1 tmux session going on. C is usually Clt.

Answer (score 294, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>

(assuming default bindings)

The first <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> is interpreted by your local *tmux* (because it is the first to see all your keystrokes). The second <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> is a command that causes your local tmux to send a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to its active pane; this generated <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> arrives at the remote *tmux*. The <kbd>D</kbd> passes through the local *tmux* unchanged; when it gets to the remote *tmux* it triggers the `detach` command.

1. You type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.
   Your local *tmux* interprets it as the prefix key; nothing is sent to the processes running under the local *tmux*.
2. You type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.
   Your local *tmux* has it bound to the `send-prefix` command.

   1. Your local *tmux* sends a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to the process running in the active pane (*ssh*).
   2. *ssh* forwards it (through *sshd*, etc.) to the process running on the remote end (remote *tmux*).
      Your remote *tmux* interprets it as the prefix key; nothing is sent to the processes running under the remote *tmux*.
3. You type <kbd>D</kbd>.
   Your local *tmux* passes it through normally (since the second <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> finished a full command key sequence for the local *tmux*).
   Your remote *tmux* has it bound to `detach-client`; it detaches the active client.

This is the same as when you need to send a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to any program running inside a *tmux* session. If you wanted to send <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to your normal shell (e.g. because your shell is using Emacs-style editing where <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> is `backward-char` (and you dislike using the arrow keys)) you would need to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to get a single <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to the shell.

Comment: Alternatively, I've frequently seen the use of ```C-a C-a``` to jump to the last active window. Under such circumstances try ```C-a a d``` to detach. Thanks!

Comment: **Note**: the combo I mention above would only be available if the ```a``` key is bound instead of ```b``` in the user's tmux.conf.

Comment: My outer tmux uses `C-a` and the inner one `C-b`, and to be able to detach from the inner one the only thing that works for me is `C-a C-b-b d`, but I don't get why do I need the second `b`

Comment: Just a reminder to allow folks to enable this option if they don't have default keybindings: you can run the `:` command to run a tmux command interactively, and then set up a binding via the `bind-key -n j send-prefix` command.  In this example I wanted to bind `j` to send the prefix.
Otherwise, use Dave's answer: use the `tmux detach` command.

Comment: On Mac it was `command + b` then `d` to detach the tmux session.

Comment: >tmux detach
failed to connect to server  . it doesn't work for me. ctrl-b then d works.

Answer (score 82):

Another way to do it without worrying about the keybindings making it to the right tmux instance is to type `tmux detach` in the remote tmux session.

Answer (score 11):

I tried the first answer without success.

I was able to get the results I wanted by doing the following:

`tmux attach`

I entered tmux and saw the other session was still attached

So I detached my current session to get back to a shell: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>

Then I issued the following:
`tmux attach -d`

This says to attach to the default session, and detach all other sessions currently attached.  See the man page under **Clients and Sessions**

> **attach-session** [-dr] [-t target-session]
> (alias: attach)
> If run from outside tmux, create a new client in the current terminal and attach it to
> target-session.  If used from inside, switch the current client.  *If -d is specified, any other
> clients attached to the session are detached.*  -r signifies the client is read-only (only keys bound
> to the detach-client command have any effect)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to try an other option  follow below steps

1. detach current tmux session with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> . So that you now you go to normal terminal command line prompt.
2. Do a  `tmux ls` . Look for session that is currently attached
3. Execute this command to detach the already attached session `tmux detach-client -s <attached_session_name>`

Answer (score 2):

I prefer `tmux detach`, it doesn't require a keyboard since it's a command.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you have modified your tmux config to use something other than `Ctrl+b` in both tmux sessions you still need to press `Ctrl+b` the second time.

For example my binding is `Ctrl+/` in both tmux sessions so I press:

```
C-/ C-b d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> to detach and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> to see all sessions, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> to open a tmux session inside a tmux session