# Kill tmux when ssh is started

Tags: ssh, tmux, kill

I have a server with tmux and a client with tmux. If I connect to my server I have running 2 tmux sessions, one from the client and one from the server. Is there a way to detach the clients sessions when connected to ssh, and reattach it when I close ssh?

Comment: What do you mean "detach the client's sessions"? Do you mean: Upon sshing to the server, only display the active (the one that ran ssh) **client** tmux pane (with the possibility of using tmux on the server)?

Comment: Yes, I want to detach the session that was started first(the one on my home PC) and only display the one that is running on my server

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is really possible, but with the combination of [maximizing a tmux pane](https://superuser.com/a/576505/82434) by typing

> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>z</kbd>

and sending the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> twice to [interact with the remote tmux session](https://superuser.com/a/249671/82434), you should achieve your goal.

Comment: OK, i will try this later, seems to be quite a good workaround