# How can I detach from a remote tmux session that is displayed within a local tmux session?

Tags: ssh, tmux

On my local computer I have tmux open. Within this tmux I have a reverse SSH connection to a remote computer. On this remote computer a opened tmux. I want to detach from the tmux session on the remote computer. How can I do this? I've tried something like `C a` `C a` `d`.

Comment: Is your prefix keystroke really Ctrl+a on the local computer? By default it's Ctrl+b in `tmux`. People being used to `screen` set `Ctrl+a` though. Have you? What is the prefix on the remote computer?

Comment: this may help you: https://superuser.com/questions/249659/how-to-detach-a-tmux-session-that-itself-already-in-a-tmux/249671